# Find the probability that exactly two large or exactly one green t-shirt is selected

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The problem statement is:

A box contains $6$ red T-shirts in which $4$ are large and $2$ are small size, $5$ white T-shirts in which $2$ are large and $3$ are small size, and $7$ green T-shirts in which $3$ are large and $4$ are small size.

Draw $3$ T-shirts from the box at random without replacement. What is the probability that exactly $2$ are large or exactly $1$ is green.

What I have tried so far is breaking it up into the case where you draw two large sizes, which I got $\left( \frac{9}{18} \right) \left( \frac8{17}\right)\left(\frac9{16}\right)$ and the case where you draw $1$ green which I got $\left( \frac7{18}\right)\left(\frac{11}{17}\right)\left(\frac{10}{16}\right)$, and add those together.  But I wasn't sure how to consider the combinations of those events, or if I even needed to. I also wasn't sure if I was overcounting since the problem statement said or, and I don't think those are mutually exclusive events.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Isn't the second case simply $\dbinom{7}{1}$?

Comment: @Gigili  No.  Since we are selecting three t-shirts, to get exactly one green t-shirt, we must select one of seven green t-shirts and two of the other eleven t-shirts, so the number of favorable cases is $\binom{7}{1}\binom{11}{2}$.  Since we are selecting three of the eighteen t-shirts, the probability that exactly one green t-shirt is selected is $$\frac{\binom{7}{1}\binom{11}{2}}{\binom{18}{3}}$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ha! I was pretty close to the correct answer! =) Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @Doadle  When you calculated the probability of obtaining two large as $$\left(\frac{9}{18}\right)\left(\frac{8}{17}\right)\left(\frac{9}{16}\right)$$ you calculated the probability of obtaining a large t-shirt, another large t-shirt, then a small t-shirt in that order.  However, the small t-shirt could also have been selected first or second, so you would have to multiply your probability by $3$ to obtain the correct answer.  For similar reasons, you would have to multiply the probability you found for drawing exactly one green t-shirt by $3$ to obtain the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have a total of $18$ t-shirts, of which $4 + 2 + 3 = 9$ are large and $2 + 3 + 4 = 9$ are small.  Hence, the probability of selecting exactly two large t-shirts is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{9}{2}\dbinom{9}{1}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$
since we must choose two of the nine large t-shirts and one of the nine small t-shirts while selecting three of the eighteen t-shirts.

We have $7$ green t-shirts and $18 - 7 = 11$ t-shirts that are not green.  Hence, the probability that exactly one green t-shirt is selected is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{7}{1}\dbinom{11}{2}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$

If we add the above results, we will have counted those cases in which exactly two large t-shirts and exactly one green t-shirt are selected twice.  We only want to count them once, so we must subtract them from the total.

More formally, given events $A$ and $B$, 
$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

How can we select exactly two large t-shirts and exactly one green t-shirt?

There are two possibilities.

1. We could choose two large t-shirts that are not green and one small green t-shirt.
2. We could choose one large green t-shirt, one large t-shirt that is not green, and one small t-shirt that is not green.

Two large t-shirts that are not green and one small green t-shirt:  There are $4 + 2 = 6$ large t-shirts that are not green and $4$ small green t-shirts.  Hence, the probability that we choose two large t-shirts that are not green and one small green t-shirt is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$

One large green t-shirt, one large t-shirt that is not green, and one small t-shirt that is not green:  There are $3$ large green t-shirts, $6$ large t-shirts that are not green, and $2 + 3 = 5$ small t-shirts that are not green.  Therefore, the probability that we select one large green t-shirt, one large t-shirt that is not green, and one small t-shirt that is not green is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$

Since the two cases are mutually exclusive, the probability that exactly two large t-shirts and exactly one green t-shirt are selected is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{4}{1} + \dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$

Therefore, the probability that exactly two large t-shirts or exactly one green t-shirt is selected when three t-shirts are selected is

> $$\frac{\dbinom{9}{2}\dbinom{9}{1} + \dbinom{7}{1}\dbinom{11}{2} - \dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{4}{1} - \dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{6}{1}\dbinom{5}{1}}{\dbinom{18}{3}}$$

Comment: The fact that the question is case 1 "or" case 2 does not make any differences, does it?

Comment: @Gigili The word or means that we obtain a favorable result if exactly two large t-shirts are selected, if exactly one green t-shirt is selected, or exactly two large and one green t-shirt is selected.  If you are asking why I broke the case in which exactly two large and one green t-shirt into two cases, it is because they are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, which allowed me to simply add the results.

Comment: Would you mind giving a numerical approximation of that result, if you have it somewhere? I'd like to compare it to my own calculation done another way.. Thanks!

Comment: @ringø I obtain $$\frac{559}{816} \approx 0.685$$

Comment: Yes! Using a monte-carlo based algorithm I get `0.68511777` ... thanks